# How to make a long query with a WHERE IN using Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a large database with about 500 gigs of column data. I am trying to access the data using Spark on DataBricks, but the query is too long to let me get the data which I am interested in. I am new to this, so please excuse me if the question does not make complete sense.

The only way I can do it right now is to break down the query and use a portion of it and repeat it.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM myDataTable
WHERE rollID in ('1', '2', '148', '123', '21432'....)
```

Expected: get all the data at once so that I can do some analysis on the cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a `WHERE IN` you can do this with a `JOIN`. In this case you might want to use a [`LEFT SEMI JOIN`](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/select.html#joins).

```
SELECT * FROM myDataTable t LEFT SEMI JOIN list l ON t.rollID = l.rollID
```

To do this you'd need to create a table / dataframe that contains your 'where in' values, and you can conceive of this as using the join to perform a filter. You may gain value from specifying that the filter / list dataframe is to be broadcast, i.e. copy the entire table to all executors, but perhaps Spark is smart enough to do that for you.

Comment: SELECT * FROM myDataTable t LEFT SEMI JOIN df_user l ON t.userid = l.userid


I tried this, but it seems like I am hitting a syntax issue. What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: Don't know - what message do you see?

Comment: I was able to get it to work. Thanks! Instead of SEMI JOIN, I did an inner since I was looking for a 1:Many relation. Really appreciate it.

Comment: So I did try that last night, but unfortunately I need 15 reputation before I can give an upvote. But I will revisit this post when I do have 15 reputation points.